# GestureDetector() doesn't have "onTap" property when it wraps a Text Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my `Text` pressable, so I wrapped it inside a `GestureDetector` but to my surprise, it doesn't have `onTap: () {}` property anymore. screenshot below:

[image]

**CODE:**

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap(){},
    child: Text(
      '-',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

`onTap: () {`

not

`onTap () {`

Comment: ahhhhhh. you are life saver, I don't know why and how i missed it. -_- .. will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to do so

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess because otherwise you could no longer copy paste. You could wrap it with a button or ListTile, though

Comment: No, I just missed the `colons` "`:`"